# node.js variavel recebe valor undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

estou tentando pegar a resposta de uma API, dentro da função o body recebe o JSON mas fora da função o valor é definido como undefined

```
async function getJSON(){
    var options = {
        url: "https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/json/all",
        method: 'GET'
    }
    request(options, function(error, response, body){
        console.log(JSON.parse(body))
        return JSON.parse(body)     
    });
};
var cota = getJSON();
console.log(cota)
```

no console tenho as seguintes saidas:

```
Promise { undefined }

{
  USD: {
    code: 'USD',
    codein: 'BRL',
    name: 'Dólar Comercial',
    high: '5.1951',
    low: '5.101',
    varBid: '0.0953',
    pctChange: '1.87',
    bid: '5.1935',
    ask: '5.1966',
    timestamp: '1585601996',
    create_date: '2020-03-30 18:00:00'
  }...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está tentando executar uma função assíncrona (`async`) sem aguardar o resultado, por isso seu `console.log` está mostrando uma `Promise`. Para aguardar a resolução da promessa, você pode utilizar a função `then`:

```
getJSON().then(console.log);
```

Ou utilize a cláusula `await` dentro de outra função `async`:

```
(async () => {
  const cota = await getJSON();
  console.log(cota);
})();
```

---

> [**Funções assíncronas**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas)
>
> A declaração **async function** define uma função assíncrona, que retorna um objeto [AsyncFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction).
>
> Você também pode definir funções assíncronas usando uma [expressão async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function).
>
> Quando uma função assíncrona é chamada, ela retorna uma [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Quando a função assíncrona retorna um valor, a `Promise` será resolvida com o valor retornado. Quando a função assíncrona lança uma exceção ou algum valor, a `Promise` será rejeitada com o valor lançado.
>
> Uma função assíncrona pode conter uma expressão [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), que pausa a execução da função assíncrona e espera pela resolução da `Promise` passada, e depois retoma a execução da função assíncrona e retorna o valor resolvido.

Comment: ela funciona agora, mas como eu exporto o que o cota armazenou para outra parte do codigo? eu só consigo usar o cota no console.log